# npm test/ jest not working

Tags: reactjs, npm, jestjs

I am trying to run a test with react/jest. When I do npm test /jest, I am getting the following error:

```
 > @ test /Users/suparnasoman/Downloads/create-react-app-master
> node packages/react-scripts/scripts/test.js --env=jsdom

module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'jest'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/suparnasoman/Downloads/create-react-app-master/packages/react-scripts/scripts/test.js:26:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

Comment: Run `npm install` first

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if the npm package is installed successfully.
2. If the installation is successful check if it is installed globally/locally.
3. If local, you might need to provide the absolute path `node_modules/bin/jest`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the jest module is missing, did you try `npm --save install jest`, or `npm install` as Chase mentioned?